# Connect with my local .mdf database (correct code)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to finalize a software with local database automatically installed when any one setup the final.exe program, but I cannot connect and design code with my local database.

```
class Class1
{
    internal static string x = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\Prog\Try\StrorPro_v1.3\StrorPro_v1.3\StoreProData_v1.2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
}
```

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Class1.x)) {
    cn.Open();
    string cm = "select id from item_new_customer where cust='" + textBox2.Text +
        "' order by id";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cm, cn)) {
        ...
```

Comment: using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Class1.x))
            {
                cn.Open();
                string cm = "select id from item_new_customer where cust='" + textBox2.Text + "' order by id";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cm, cn))
                {

Comment: Please avoid adding additional information via comment. Consider editing you question with the additional information.

Comment: LocalDb is a database engine designed for development only and must be installed. You cannot assume users have this. If you need a database per application instance consider [Sqlite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Comment: There is no need to include the attached filename which can lead to exceptions.  The DAtaSource should match the instance of the database on the login window of SQL Server Management Studio.  The database is attached to the Server and owns the mdf file.  So you can either set the default database in the connection string or add a "USE DATABASE_NAME" to you queries to make sure correct database is used.  The mdf filename is part of the attach statement and the Server know the location so it is not needed in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should look similar to the example below.  It isn’t necessary to reference an MDF or other file.  `Data Source` refers to the SQL Server instance where the database is hosted.  `Initial Catalog` will be the database that all SQL statements without the USE keyword or a three part identifier, i.e. Database.Schema.Table, are sent to.  When SSPI is used for `Integrated Security` the Windows credentials that are used to run the application will be used in the authentication process.  True is equivalent to SSPI, however it’s recommended to use SSPI.  To use SQL Server authentication specify a user ID and password for the User ID and Password properties, and set `Integrated Security` to false.  For more details on additional connection string properties you can refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
“Data Source=YourSQLServerInstance;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```